# How to change character of dynamically created href value without removing hash with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, character-encoding, href

I wanted to change id and another element href value which are created dynamically

I did this and it is working for id but not working with href it is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.cstm_title h3').each(function(){
var charMap = {Ç:'c',Ö:'o',Ş:'s',İ:'i',I:'i',Ü:'u',Ğ:'g',ç:'c',ö:'o',ş:'s',ı:'i',ü:'u',ğ:'g'};
this.id = this.id.replace(/Ç|Ö|Ş|İ|I|Ü|Ğ|ç|ö|ş|ı|ü|ğ/g, function(matched){
  return charMap[matched];
});
});
});


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#cstm_content a').each(function(){
var charMap = {Ç:'c',Ö:'o',Ş:'s',İ:'i',I:'i',Ü:'u',Ğ:'g',ç:'c',ö:'o',ş:'s',ı:'i',ü:'u',ğ:'g'};
this.href = this.hash.substr(1).replace(/Ç|Ö|Ş|İ|I|Ü|Ğ|ç|ö|ş|ı|ü|ğ/g, function(matched){
  return charMap[matched];
});
});
});
```

And this is the result for id it is working but for href not working.

```
<div class="test"><div id="cstm_content" class="list-group">    
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="%C4%B0zmir">İzmir</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="%C3%9Csk%C3%BCp">Üsküp</a>
</div>

<div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#cstm_content" data-offset="30" class="scrollspy-example">
  <div class="cstm_card">
      <div class="cstm_title">
      <h3 class="cstm_c_title" id="izmir">İzmir</h3>
      <p class="cstm_c">Here is paragraph</p>   
      <h3 class="cstm_c_title" id="uskup">Üsküp</h3>
      <p class="cstm_c">Here is paragraph</p> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am beginner in jquery I am creating all with googleing but couldn't find solution for this. If there is easier method that you will provide I will be happy.

Comment: this.href = this.hash.substr(1) should be: this.href = this.href.substr(1) ?

Comment: I @Svela and in your solution result is being 
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="ttps://www.example.com/test/#%C4%B0zmir">İzmir</a>

Original is
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#İzmir">İzmir</a>
I would like to get result
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#izmir">İzmir</a>

Comment: Ok, not sure if I really understood the problem then. Where did example.com come from? It the link is like that you could split href: var urlArray = this.href.split('#'); this.href ='#' + urlArray[1].replace('...

Comment: @Svela Thank you so much with your help. I have dynamically created element attributes that have Turkish characters and with Jquery I want to replace Turkish characters with English ones. Maybe you can have another solution to solve it.?

Comment: This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/dg0zasLh/

Comment: @Svela thank you very much for your solution also I found other way that I posted below, it is working, I hope it is good enough for standards as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#cstm_content a').attr('href', function (_, href) {
    var charMap = {Ç:'c',Ö:'o',Ş:'s',İ:'i',I:'i',Ü:'u',Ğ:'g',ç:'c',ö:'o',ş:'s',ı:'i',ü:'u',ğ:'g'};
    return href.replace(/Ç|Ö|Ş|İ|I|Ü|Ğ|ç|ö|ş|ı|ü|ğ/g, function(matched){
  return charMap[matched];
});
});
});


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.cstm_title h3').attr('id', function (_, id) {
    var charMap = {Ç:'c',Ö:'o',Ş:'s',İ:'i',I:'i',Ü:'u',Ğ:'g',ç:'c',ö:'o',ş:'s',ı:'i',ü:'u',ğ:'g'};
    return id.replace(/Ç|Ö|Ş|İ|I|Ü|Ğ|ç|ö|ş|ı|ü|ğ/g, function(matched){
  return charMap[matched];
});
});
});
```